# Want reset animation of external swf file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have added an external SWF file into fla file using AS3 Code

I set dynamic textbox text and showing using addChild it works fine but after some time I remove the child then again change the value and again showing same object using addChild method but second time it is not animating.

I think it is in stop keyframe. I want to reset. Please advice me how I will do that.

I set dynamic textbox data like this

```
externalSWF.main.tatextbox.text = "a";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
externalSWF.main.gotoAndPlay(1);
```

if the animation is in the *main* MovieClip.